# transform json column in a dataframe

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

I have a dataframe in which two columns are JSON objects. Something like this:

```
id     choice               name    host                                
002   {'option': 'true'}    Bob     {'city': {'name': 'A'}}
003   {'option': 'false'}   Ana     {'city': {'name': 'B'}}
004   {'option': 'false'}   Nic     {'city': {'name': 'C'}}
```

I wish for the column result to only be the final string in columns `choice` and `host` (true, false, A, B, C...)

i was able to do it to column `host` with the following formula

```
df['host'] = (df.loc[:, 'host']
                    .apply(lambda x: x['city']['name']))
```

This was succesful. However, when i apply something similar to column `choice`

```
df['choice'] = (df.loc[:, 'choice']
                         .apply(lambda x: x['option']))
```

i get `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

How could i get a `choice` column with "true" and "false"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us use `str.get`

```
df.choice.str.get('option')
0     true
1    false
2    false
Name: choice, dtype: object

df.host.str.get('city').str.get('name')
0    A
1    B
2    C
Name: host, dtype: object
```

First make sure they are `object` in your two columns , `dict` if not , do the conversion via `ast.literal_eval`

```
import ast
df[['choice','host']]=df[['choice','host']].applymap(ast.literal_eval)
```